# Cannot install a podfile

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I've installed Cocoapods, run pod setup, created a pod file and then when i try to install it,  get the following errors.

```
    fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.35.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:13:in `report': incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.35.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:58:in `report_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.7.0/lib/claide/command.rb:300:in `handle_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.7.0/lib/claide/command.rb:274:in `rescue in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.7.0/lib/claide/command.rb:264:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.35.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:45:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.35.0/bin/pod:43:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

This is what's in my podfile

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod ‘pop’, ‘~> 1.0′
```

I've uninstalled cocoa pods and re-installed but with no luck. Even tried the following solution which worked for others having problems with pod install but to no avail.

```
$ sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
$ pod setup
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it was a temporary problem, possibly on cocoa pods side. Re-tried 'pod install' today and it worked without a problem.

Answer (score 2):

This occurred for me when I had edited my Podfile with Textedit, and instead of normal single quotes, there were the backtick marks ie:

I got this:     ′
Instead of this: '